# Install module right after installing python

Tags: python

Recently, I have been trying to install a module right after installing Python. I am making a small program that tampers with a game’s memory and wanted to package it into an `EXE` for easier use and distribution.

What ends up happening is the module I am using `Pymem` does not work while packaged (gives error every time). So I have resorted to making an `EXE` that installs python but since the `env` path variables do not update immediately in the same `CMD` session, I cannot use pip to install anything.

Any insight or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If on Windows, `py.exe` (the python launcher) will already be in the path.  `py -m pip install pymem` should then work.

Answer (score -1):

Install `pymem`. This should work for you.

```
python -m pip install pymem
```